# Which statistical test do I use with 2 independent groups and 1 dependent variable

Tags: regression, anova, categorical-data, lognormal-distribution, qq-plot

I want to test if there is a difference in the mean distance travelled (`Afstand`) by sex (`Geslacht`) and age class (`Leeftijdsklasse`), and if there is an interaction between the independent variables. I was thinking about a factorial ANOVA (two-way anova?) since the independent variables are of categorical origin if I am correct. Next to that, my data is not normaliy distributed, but seems to follow a more normal distribution when I take the log scale (see r-code beneath). Could anyone guide me in the right direction which test I should use, since my statistical knowledge is limited.

Checking for normality:

```
qqnorm(Afstand_totaal$Afstand)
qqline(Afstand_totaal$Afstand)

Afstand_totaal$Log <- log(Afstand_totaal$Afstand)
qqnorm(Afstand_totaal$Log)
qqline(Afstand_totaal$Log)
```

[image]

I tried the following:

```
model1 <- lm(Log ~ Lengteklasse * Geslacht, data = Afstand_totaal)
anova(model1)
```

Dput(Afstand_totaal)

```
structure(list(HEX_Tag_ID = c("3D6.153413ECBC", "3D6.153413ECE0", 
"3D6.153413EF72", "3D6.15341B9871", "3D6.15341B9B1D", "3D6.15341B9B36", 
"3D6.15341BA2E5", "3D6.15341BA3BA", "3D6.15341BA4AA", "3D6.15341BAACC", 
"3D6.15341BAD53", "3D6.15341BADE3", "3D6.15341BAE18", "3D6.15341BAE4D", 
"3D6.15341BB40B", "3D6.15341BB46B", "3D6.15341BB664", "3D6.15341BBB4F", 
"3D6.15341BBCBC", "3D6.15341BBFB5", "3D6.15341BBFEF", "3D6.15341BC0A1", 
"3D6.15341BC0FB", "3D6.15341BC232", "3D6.15341BC301", "3D6.15341BC38D", 
"3D6.15341BC475", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC9D8", "3D6.15341BCB9A", 
"3D6.15341BCBFE", "3D6.15341BCF0C", "3D6.15341BCF8A", "3D6.15341BD0D4", 
"3D6.15341BD291", "3D6.15341BD531", "3D6.15341BD71B", "3D6.15341BDE9F", 
"3D6.15341BDF75", "3D6.15341BE2C4", "3D6.15341BE5B6", "3D6.15341BE8C3", 
"3D6.15341BEBB7", "3D6.15341BF00C", "3D6.15341BF0EF", "3D6.15341BF1FD", 
"3D6.15341BF4E3", "3D6.15341BF6C8", "3D6.15341BF8F1", "3D6.15341BF949"
), `Lengte_(cm)` = c(9, 10.5, 10.7, 10.6, 10.6, 9.9, 7.7, 8.1, 
8.2, 9.1, 10.6, 9.3, 11.2, 12.1, 11.2, 10.5, 11.5, 9.7, 11.1, 
12, 7.2, 10.2, 12, 8.6, 10.1, 11.1, 8.9, 11.2, 10.9, 11.4, 11, 
10.5, 11.1, 11.1, 9.2, 8.9, 10.5, 11.5, 9.4, 10.4, 11.2, 10.4, 
9.1, 9.2, 10, 10.1, 10.5, 11, 10.7, 7.8), Geslacht = c("man", 
"man", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", 
"man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw"), Lengteklasse = structure(c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "factor"), Afstand = c(21.1834468927117, 
93.1253995491358, 128.22585693041, 39.3908797000505, 89.4085966505682, 
28.0091903667337, 48.9507392648961, 9.06092738075898, 87.4036418644136, 
78.8848357607789, 14.4020923826949, 33.1703060554382, 16.863907761852, 
81.5876175999678, 77.2698044685365, 39.0163205128401, 147.309311625921, 
130.380354693403, 89.5107812574272, 14.2467611691203, 5.30337147483878, 
47.5657994401398, 130.128954913079, 127.569269170472, 102.432743613457, 
77.2533059033879, 76.3586221674896, 338.157708423444, 5.80260027919226, 
262.482780179362, 163.732597097985, 56.8617021433052, 154.167152561441, 
181.044336131325, 169.442778988405, 51.1649746701647, 17.0785963597442, 
86.4750591502781, 18.0351392442254, 319.219125470678, 31.5216953633101, 
205.65646452708, 30.369464944265, 110.577121490526, 80.8481248587015, 
57.6113408482598, 86.0274001556079, 35.3909042657002, 133.404917998323, 
10.1481746141447), Log = c(3.05322006974189, 4.53394696715104, 
4.85379321627433, 3.67353430981418, 4.49321683695878, 3.33253268370373, 
3.89081447131184, 2.20397147472364, 4.47053695072258, 4.367989013699, 
2.66737350038011, 3.50165507979123, 2.82517570281435, 4.40167750535718, 
4.3473032514458, 3.66398003328174, 4.99253453685361, 4.87045598395137, 
4.49435907900281, 2.65652959450367, 1.66834274564292, 3.86211400383642, 
4.86852591965735, 4.84865950468275, 4.62920642334264, 4.34708970972804, 
4.33544095479074, 5.82351237963114, 1.75830614108386, 5.57018548056323, 
5.09823459160332, 4.04062204146429, 5.03803742002929, 5.19874195227202, 
5.1325152827361, 3.93505520947683, 2.83782600464059, 4.45985603883893, 
2.89232203510337, 5.7658777806688, 3.45067605045026, 5.32620712879011, 
3.41343766099877, 4.70571320955746, 4.39257239291188, 4.05371943804834, 
4.4546658519698, 3.56645484547768, 4.89338899935612, 2.31729384834351
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), groups = structure(list(HEX_Tag_ID = c("3D6.153413ECBC", 
"3D6.153413ECE0", "3D6.153413EF72", "3D6.15341B9871", "3D6.15341B9B1D", 
"3D6.15341B9B36", "3D6.15341BA2E5", "3D6.15341BA3BA", "3D6.15341BA4AA", 
"3D6.15341BAACC", "3D6.15341BAD53", "3D6.15341BADE3", "3D6.15341BAE18", 
"3D6.15341BAE4D", "3D6.15341BB40B", "3D6.15341BB46B", "3D6.15341BB664", 
"3D6.15341BBB4F", "3D6.15341BBCBC", "3D6.15341BBFB5", "3D6.15341BBFEF", 
"3D6.15341BC0A1", "3D6.15341BC0FB", "3D6.15341BC232", "3D6.15341BC301", 
"3D6.15341BC38D", "3D6.15341BC475", "3D6.15341BC60F", "3D6.15341BC9D8", 
"3D6.15341BCB9A", "3D6.15341BCBFE", "3D6.15341BCF0C", "3D6.15341BCF8A", 
"3D6.15341BD0D4", "3D6.15341BD291", "3D6.15341BD531", "3D6.15341BD71B", 
"3D6.15341BDE9F", "3D6.15341BDF75", "3D6.15341BE2C4", "3D6.15341BE5B6", 
"3D6.15341BE8C3", "3D6.15341BEBB7", "3D6.15341BF00C", "3D6.15341BF0EF", 
"3D6.15341BF1FD", "3D6.15341BF4E3", "3D6.15341BF6C8", "3D6.15341BF8F1", 
"3D6.15341BF949"), `Lengte_(cm)` = c(9, 10.5, 10.7, 10.6, 10.6, 
9.9, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 9.1, 10.6, 9.3, 11.2, 12.1, 11.2, 10.5, 11.5, 
9.7, 11.1, 12, 7.2, 10.2, 12, 8.6, 10.1, 11.1, 8.9, 11.2, 10.9, 
11.4, 11, 10.5, 11.1, 11.1, 9.2, 8.9, 10.5, 11.5, 9.4, 10.4, 
11.2, 10.4, 9.1, 9.2, 10, 10.1, 10.5, 11, 10.7, 7.8), Geslacht = c("man", 
"man", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", 
"man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: If you want us to comment on normality, you need to show us plots and results rather than code and data. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248189/testing-model-assumptions-in-r/580452#580452 for some general remarks on model assumption testing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The normality check is not of my main concern. I mostly want to know which test I can use for 2 independent variables of categorical data and 1 dependent variable of interval/ratio data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an ANOVA is the appropriate analysis here.

None of your variables need to be normally distributed - it is the *model residuals* that need to be (approximately) normally distributed for your inferences to be valid. Without seeing plots of your residuals, it is hard to judge whether the transformation is useful.

Comment: Thats very useful information, thank you. I am not sure why the plots are not showing in my question. I conducted a shapiro-wilk normality test: W = 0.9868, p-value = 0.1865. So this assumption is not validated if I am correct

Comment: @Pepijn95 I don't recommend normality testing, ever. It's best to judge normality of residuals based on qqplots and histograms.

Comment: @Pepijn95 You've got the plot links within the code block, which is why they do not show up. But again - if they are plots of the raw data and not the residuals, they are irrelevant.

Comment: I added a qqplot (which looks normally distributed) but I am not able to add it correctly to my question unfortunately. If you have tips to show it properly I would really appreciate it :).

Comment: @Pepijn95 As I said, the link is within the code block. But I believe I've addressed your basic question here already - correct?

Comment: I do understand something is wrong with the link being in the code block. But I do not know how to add the link without this format, as the website automatically generate this code block. As for of the main question you answered me in a helpful way, thanks for that!

Comment: @Pepijn95 I fixed it

Comment: But to reiterate: I don't know what the qqplot represents and the distribution of the raw data is irrelevant.

Comment: for the purpose of future posts... Is it just by removing the " !" ?

Comment: @Pepijn95 No - I added 3 backticks at the end of the final chunk of code to close the codeblock.